# How to make check boxs in the center align instead of left align?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
<div >
        <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
          <IndeterminateCheckbox {...getToggleHideAllColumnsProps()} /> Toggle
          All
          {allColumns.map((column) => (
            <div key={column.id}>
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" {...column.getToggleHiddenProps()} />{
                  ' '}
                {column.Header}{' '}
              </label>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

[check boxs is print in left align](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqe1F.png)

How to make check-boxs in the center align instead of left align?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with center align? Do you want to use a 'space-between' on your flex container?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using flex improperly here,
set `display:inline-block, width:auto, text-align:center` to wrapper div
this will make the whole wrapper div center aligned

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?? This is an example.

```css
.allinputs{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
  
   }

.myinputs {
   display:grid;
   }
```

```html
<div class="allinputs">
 <div class="myinputs">
  <label> Toggle All </label>
  <center>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </center>
 </div>

 <div class="myinputs">
  <label> Device Id </label>
  <center>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </center>
  </div>
  
   <div class="myinputs">
  <label> Water Temperature </label>
  <center>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </center>
  </div>
  
   <div class="myinputs">
  <label> Air Temperature</label>
  <center>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </center>
 </div>
 
</div>
```